# Naming convention recommendation for using mysql in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, naming-conventions, backend

please give me your guidance.

I'm using node with mysql database (without using orm).

i use snake_case naming convention for mysql.

my question is:

in node, 
should i use snake_case or use camelCase ?

for e.g. at models/movie.js:

**snake_case:**

`return db.execute(SELECT title, daily_rental_rate FROM movies);`

the result sent to the client:

```
{
title: 'abc',
daily_rental_rate: 20
}
```

**camel_case:**

`return db.execute(SELECT title, daily_rental_rate as dailyRentalRate FROM movies);`

the result sent to the client:

```
{
title: 'abc',
dailyRentalRate: 20
}
```

thank you so much /\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fixed convention for JSON casing, however most APIs tend to use camelCase for properties, include Google, see their style guide [here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml?showone=Property_Name_Format#Property_Name_Guidelines).

You can also map object properties within JavaScript, you don't have to do this manually in your queries. This allows you to be relatively flexible with your casing, even changing to kebab-case or snake_case if you wish to later on. This example uses the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library to convert object case.

```
const _ = require("lodash");

function objectToCamelCase(obj) {
    return _.mapKeys(obj, (v, k) => _.camelCase(k))
}

let rows = db.execute("SELECT title, daily_rental_rate FROM movies");
console.log("Result (snake_case): ", rows);
rows = rows.map(objectToCamelCase);
console.log("Result (camelCase):", rows);
```

The results might look like so:

**Result (snake_case):**

```
[
    {
        "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
        "daily_rental_rate": "€2.99"
    },
    {
        "title": "Ferris Bueller's Day Off",
        "daily_rental_rate": "€2.99"
    }
]
```

**Result (camelCase):**

```
[
    {
        "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
        "dailyRentalRate": "€2.99"
    },
    {
        "title": "Ferris Bueller's Day Off",
        "dailyRentalRate": "€2.99"
    }
]
```

Comment: Noted. Thank you very much for your help and advice /\ :)

Comment: Glad to be of help! Happy coding!

Comment: @Terry Lennox Very good answer - just what I was looking for. 

But how will this affect the server performance? 

E.g. if we have 10000 users making requests, all this case conversion which is not a business logic and could be avoided will happen.

Comment: This shouldn't affect server performance in any significant way, case conversion should be cheap relative to the queries themselves. If in doubt one could test with case conversion and without.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've investigated this further and several sources confirm that reading from the DB and performing the business logic will take much more time compared to names conversion, thus this approach is acceptable.
I will go with it and maybe perform some profiling when the app grows to test this on real data.

Best regards.